# Как передавать поток с видеокамеры, взятый с помощью opencv в порт

Tags: c++, сокет, opencv, web-camera

Как передать поток opencv, взятый с видеокамеры в порт. По идее, для unix нет особой разницы куда записывать данные, порт и файл она воспринимает одинаково. Можно ли записывать видеопоток вебкамеры в порт, подобно тому, как мы бы записывали его в файл? Как это сделать ?

```
int main()
{

    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY); 
    assert( capture );

    IplImage* frame= nullptr;

    cvNamedWindow("capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true)
    {
         frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    }
}
```

Comment: какой порт? rs232?

Comment: @PavelGridin, сетевой

Comment: тогда, да, как в примере выше, правда я для портируемости пользуюсь SFML

Comment: @PavelGridin, вряд ли этот пример подйодет. Нужно чтоб бразуер понял формат

Comment: так это web-сервер надо делать получается

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, проблема в том,что я хочу ссылаться на этот порт как на файл в scr